# How do I operationalize the Cold-Blooded Oracle Curse?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society, oracle

I'm creating a nagaji oracle, and stumbled upon the Cold-Blooded Oracle Curse from the *Monster Codex*. It reads:

> Your blood turns sluggish without sufficient heat, and you must seek warmth and shelter earlier than most. This oracle curse is common among lizardfolk and other oracles with the reptilian subtype. You take a –4 penalty on saves against cold spells and effects, and whenever you fail such a saving throw, you are staggered for 1 round. You can survive without food four times longer than a typical creature of your species before you begin to starve.

Initially I was going to take Clouded Vision as my curse, but this one seems much better. The only downside that I'm really seeing is "a –4 penalty on saves against cold spells and effects." However, the first sentence has me a little tripped up. I'm not sure whether that is supposed to add flavor, or whether there is a set of game mechanics that actually determine how fast I would need to "seek warmth and shelter."

Is there a way to operationalize the first sentence, or is that just flavor given to the curse? If there are rules governing the first sentence, how do I apply them in PFS scenarios that generally have shorter in-game time frames?

Comment: The big question here is whether a saving throw to avoid non-lethal damage triggered by cold weather is a cold effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the [oracle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/)'s cold-blooded [oracle's curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/oracle-curses/) says, "Your blood turns sluggish without sufficient heat, and you must seek warmth and shelter earlier than most," this appears to be just flavor. Although the [Environment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules/) on [Cold](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules/#Cold) says, "A character cannot recover from the damage dealt by a cold environment until she gets out of the cold and warms up again," there's no game definition of *earlier than most*.

It's likely that you'll be expected to role-playing the oracle's sluggishness and early desire for warmth in cold climes, but, by way of mechanical effects, such an oracle *only* suffers, as described by the curse, the penalty on saving throws against cold effects and the additional effect on a failed saving throw against cold effects.

Answer (score 5):

The curse itself tells you how to operationalize that line:

> You take a –4 penalty on saves against cold spells and effects, and whenever you fail such a saving throw, you are staggered for 1 round.

This *is* how the curse represents the opening flavor mechanically. The saving throw penalty makes you suffer from the cold “earlier than most,” since you (mostly likely) fail the save sooner, and the staggered condition makes you “sluggish.”

Please do note that a –4 penalty is *huge*, in the mathematics of the game, and the staggered condition is very serious. This curse will make you far more vulnerable to the cold than the flavor might suggest. I strongly recommend that you only take this if you have strong trust in your DM’s ability to avoid metagaming.